# ivar_getTypeEncoding return "" in swift

Tags: swift

code like it:

test class

```
class test {
    var name: String!
    var age: String!
    var pu: Int!
}
```

test function

```
func variableMap() {
    let ivars = class_copyIvarList(test.self, &temp.count)
    if ivars != nil {

        for i in 0..<Int(temp.count) {
            let thisIvar: Ivar = ivars[i]
            let type = ivar_getTypeEncoding(thisIvar)
            let str = String(CString: type, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var key = String(UTF8String: ivar_getName(thisIvar))
            let type1 = String(CString: type, encoding: NSProprietaryStringEncoding)


            print("\(key!)")
            print("\(type1!)")
        }
        free(ivars)
    }
}
```

but print

```
name

age 

pu
```

Question:

I use `let type = ivar_getTypeEncoding(thisIvar)` but return "" not the property's type. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: `ivar_getTypeEncoding` isn't available in Swift https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/

Comment: Why on earth are you using NSProprietaryStringEncoding?

Comment: because I use NSUTF8StringEncoding return "", so I try the another encoding, but also error

Answer (score 0):

Swift is probably using internal wrappers to bridge these `ivars` into ObjC. The only way I could make it work was to defined the class `test` in ObjC:

```
@interface test : NSObject

@property NSString * name;
@property NSString * age;
@property int pu;

@end
```

You can defined all the properties there and then extend the class in Swift.

Also you got an error in your code:

```
let type1 = String(CString: type, encoding: NSProprietaryStringEncoding)
                                            ^ should be NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use the objc class, it work find for me